# How to get the list of links in a Wikipedia article in order of appearance

Tags: data-acquisition, parsing, wikipedia

I can get a list of links in a Wikipedia article using [`WikipediaData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WikipediaData.html):

```
sortedLinks = WikipediaData["County", "LinksList"];
sortedLinks // Length
```

> ```
> 586
> ```

I need a list of links in order of their appearance in the article.
I tried to write a function to extract the links from the article's code:

```
unsortedWikiLinks[title_String] := 
 DeleteDuplicates@Append[
   StringCases[WikipediaData[title, "ArticleWikicode"], 
    "[[" ~~ link : Except["]" | "|", _] .. :> 
     ToUpperCase[StringTake[link, 1]] <> StringDrop[link, 1]], 
  title]
```

However, many links are missed because `"ArticleWikicode"` does not parse the templates in the article.

```
unsortedLinks = unsortedWikiLinks["County"];
unsortedLinks // Length
```

> ```
> 244
> ```

The official Wikipedia API has an [action to parse the templates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext#parse), however I can't find this option in  Mathematica's implementation.

How to get a list of links in order of their appearance with Mathematica?

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see this part of the API exposed in WikipediaData. 
If you want to use that part of the API, I would use it directly without WikipediaData using URLFetch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Searke](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/144/searke) in the comments has a good idea. I found that one can get the article code with templates expanded by using `query` with [`revisions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions) (there may be other ways). Here is an implementation of such an API query using [`URLExecute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLExecute.html):

```
expandedWikitext[title_String] := Cases[
   URLExecute[
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
    {"format" -> "json",
     "action" -> "query",
     "titles" -> title,
     "prop" -> "revisions",
     "rvprop" -> "content",
     "rvexpandtemplates" -> "True"}], 
   ("*" -> text_String) :> text, Infinity
  ] // First
```

The above will return the code with templates expanded. Therefore, to construct an unsorted link function, do something like:

```
unsortedWikilinks[title_String] := DeleteDuplicates@Join[
   {title},
   Select[
    StringCases[
     expandedWikitext[title],
     "[[" ~~ link : Except["]" | "|" | "#", _] .. :> Capitalize@link
    ],
    ! StringContainsQ[#, ":"] &
   ]
  ]
```

(It's still a little kludgy, but it works).

```
unsortedLinks = unsortedWikiLinks["County"];
unsortedLinks // Length
```

> `586`

```
ContainsExactly[unsortedlinks, sortedlinks]
```

> `True`

Comment: Thanks, I am not familiar with `URLExecute`, so this is very helpful. Also for the `"#"` gotcha in link parsing.

Comment: @shrx, happy to help! `URLExecute` is new, but really suitable for API queries (and similar to other URL post-type functions in other languages.)

Comment: I mean "get-type".